# Turn on Internet Management via SSH on Draytek Vigor 2960

Tags: draytek

I want to enable the web management interface on a Draytek Vigor 2960 router and have connected via SSH however bit confused as to how to configure like so. Tried like below however just shows a list of commands.

```
Vigor2960> ip6 mngt https on
       ^
apply       Apply setting
debug       show debug log
enable      Change to enable mode
fpp         Change inspection policy and packet count of FPP
help        Display an overview of the CLI syntax
history     Display the current session's command line history
logout      Logout of the current CLI session
ping        Send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network host
ping6       Send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network host
restart     Restart service
status      Get current system related status
tr069       Get current tr069 parameter value
traceroute  Print the route packets trace to network host
uci         uci command
wd_off      close watch dog, ps: watch dog is running in default after reboot

exit        Exit
```

Not sure if i need to enter a configuration mode or if that is even the correct command to enable this and was wondering how this is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out...
Typed in enable to enter enable mode, then slowly typed things and found my way around. Typing in commands seemed to give options like below and new modes had addtional commands under "..." that seemed to be mode specific. So:

```
Vigor2960# configure
applications   bandwidth      nat            object_setting system
terminal       user           vpn
```

System seemed like the place to go:

```
Vigor2960# configure system
```

From within there i could see all new modes and guessed it would be "Configure Access Control"

```
Vigor2960@config-sys# acc_ctrl get
```

To retrieve current settings.

```
acc_ctrl set web_lan_allow enable
```

Then type apply.

```
Vigor2960@config-sys# apply
```